# PHP scraping table

Tags: php

I've been on a mission to learn how to use PHP and scrape data, create a database etc.

I've been trying to scrape data from http://www.basketball-reference.com/leagues/NBA_2015.html#all_team_stats

So far I've managed to scrape just that whole section by doing this:

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init("http://www.basketball-reference.com/leagues/NBA_2015.html#all_team_stats");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
$cl = curl_exec($ch);
$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($cl);
$table = $dom->getElementById("all_team_stats");
echo "<pre>";
print_r($table);
?>
```

I'm kind of lost on how to go about scraping the individual values. I'm guessing I have to run a loop for the `<TD>` tags or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$rows = $table->getElementsByTagName('tr');
for($i=0; $i<$rows->length; $i++){
    $cols = $rows->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('td');
    for($j=0; $j<$cols->length; $j++){
        print($cols->item($j)->textContent);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much.  I'm trying to understand everything better and I'm wondering why is it if you remove the 2nd for loop and edit the first one to just print $rows, just the team names don't show up.

Comment: because $rows is a collection of DOMNodes objects. You can print the text content of the rows by

    print($rows->item($i)->textContent);